# Смена части url

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

Есть такой урл - `https://site/post/?blogger_id=16` необходимо сменить последнюю часть url с `/?blogger_id=16` на `/16`
нужно сделать такой - `https://site/post/16`

Писал эту строку в `htacces`:

```
RewriteRule ^post/([0-9]+)$ post/blogger_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

но эта запись не меняет часть url с `/?blogger_id=16` на `/16`

Comment: Учимся задавать вопросы не как посетитель детского сада, а как хотя бы начинающий программист. В частности **внятно описываем**, что  имеется в виду под "не работает", что конкретно при этом происходит.

Comment: "эта запись" и не должна менять с /?blogger_id=16 на /16. Она делает ровно наоборот - с  /16 на ?blogger_id=16

Comment: И, разумеется, никакие правки в htaccess ничего не меняют в *коде сайта*.

Comment: @Ипатьев ?blogger_id=16 - это $_GET значение?

Comment: Ну, на ламерском языке - да, это "$_GET значение"ю на нормальном, это query string, часть request uri

Comment: формально, эта строка вообще ничего не меняет в URL, а перенаправляет запрос. Если автор хочет добиться, чтобы на по ссылке `/16` открывалось старая ссылка `/?blogger_id=16` то это про `mod_rewrite`. Если же требуется, вдобавок чтобы на на страницах сайта все ссылки вида `/blogger_id=xxx` превратились в `/xxx` то это `mod_substitute`.